# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at share-modal.js:1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I met a error, I wanna fix it, but very hard, I have searched every thing in Google but no hope.
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at chrome-extension://edlifbnjlicfpckhgjhflgkeeibhhcii/js/share-modal.js:1*

[image]

When I wanna use Debugged Chrome tools-dev Extension in Visual Studio Code to fix this error, but that error hidden or what happen.

[image]

Comment: That error appears to be coming from the Screenshot Tool Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screenshot-tool-capture-e/edlifbnjlicfpckhgjhflgkeeibhhcii?hl=en-GB).  If you're not one of the developers or maintainers of this extension, then it's not a problem with your code and there's not much you can do about this error other than uninstalling this extension.

Comment: @Luke Woodward thank you so much, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the screenshot Extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).