# Disable this console messages that appears in event handlers at React

Tags: reactjs, onchange

How to disable these console messages when doing an event handler (like onChange) in react. It comes to this file called ContentScript.js but I don't know how to remove it. It's annoying and it sometimes makes me confused about the console.log message I'm reading when debuggin. The pic below is some project to show what I meant.

I'm using also the latest version of react on this. 18.1.0

[image]

This is the code.

```
    function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('')

  const onChange =(e) => setState(e.target.value)

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}><input value={state} onChange={onChange}/> <button>Submit</button></form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: As the error indicates the console error is coming from share-modal.js. What is there in that file?

Comment: This looks to be the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947412/cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-addeventlistener-at-share-modal-js1

Comment: @user700284 your right about the error. I'm still using the same chrome extension for screenshot. Thanks for that. But my concern here is about the console message when having an onChange event in the input field.

Comment: Oh.. I see..so this contentscript.js is not really part of your codebase.. In that case again it could be from one of your extensions.. May be running in incognito with all the extensions disabled could help confirm that..Also i guess there is some way to filter extensions in console.log

Comment: @user700284 yeah that seems to be correct. I can't believe it is coming from other chrome extensions that I use. Many thanks. I learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -

```
console.clear()
```

before calling your debug `console.log()`

It will clear your previous console messages.

Another workaround:

ContentScript.js is coming from your browser extension if it doesn't exist in your project. Disable all browser extension to stop getting unknown messages.

Comment: Is there better way besides just using console.clear? Because when I npm build that simple project and try to make an onChange in the input field, the console message still appears.

Comment: I think ContentScript.js is coming from your browser extension if it doesn't exist in your project. Can you check by disabling all your extension and try again? @GabAgoncillo

Comment: Wow. you're right. It seems it's because of a chrome extension that I use. I can't believe it. Many thanks to you Tamzid I learn something new.

Comment: I updated my answer with my comment. If you found my answer suitable, you can accept my answer. @GabAgoncillo